# Error in output of cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

This is a part of my matlab code:

Here, `dsig` is also a **cell array with 90 cell elements**.

```
ggg=d;                                            
decod=cell(ggg,1);                           %decod is a cell array
for m=1:ggg                                          
    k=1;
    mm=numel(dsig{m});                       %mm stores number of elements in dsig{m}
    for h=1:mm                               %run loop for each element in dsig{m}
        l=0;                                 %l is equated to 0 every time h is incremented
        if(dsig{m}(h)>0 && dsig{m}(h)<1)     %if value lies between 0 and 1
            str=num2str(dsig{m}(h));            
            str2=strrep(str,'0.','');        %remove '0.' and extract the fraction
            num=str2num(str2);                   
            l=num;                              
            rs=(k+l)-1;
            decod{m}(k:rs)=0;                %decod{m} is filled with 'l' zeros
            k=k+l;                           
        else
            decod{m}(k)=dsig{m}(h);          %values outside 0-1 range are put into the array
            k=k+1;
        end;
    end;
    disp(size(decod{m}));
end;
```

Here, whenever a fraction between 0 and 1 occurs,it must be substituted with the number of zeros equal to the fraction value. Otherwise the value in `dsig` must be put into `decod{m}`.The size of `decod{m}` must be **76800 for every `m`**. But I am getting wrong values.I have been trying to find the error for two days. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Please indent your code (in Matlab editor for example) and edit your question

Comment: Should I add comments to my code?

Comment: Well, with the indentation the code is now much more readable. As for comments, they are probably less necessary, but sure they would help too

Comment: What do you mean "it must be substituted with the number of zeros equal to the fraction value"?

Comment: If the value is 0.57 then 57 zeros must be put into the array decod{m}.I don't know if this code is right or wrong.If it is right, then I might have probably committed a mistake elsewhere.Then I can make changes to previous parts of my code.

Comment: It looks like your algorithm is ok. The size of outputs should depend on data in dsig, mostly on numbers with fraction. Are you sure they are correct? Have you tested it on a small dataset? BTW I think `k` and `h` are always equal, so you can do `rs=(h+l)-1; decod{m}(h:rs)=0;` and remove all statements with `k`.

Comment: BTW do you have any numbers <=0? If yes, they will go to else, right?

Comment: Another suggestion. May be you need to preallocate the cell elements in decode array: `decod = cellfun(@(x) zeros(1,76800), decod, 'UniformOutput',0);`

Comment: I found the error.While encoding I have used 0.30 to encode 30 continuous zeroes.While decoding this is being considered as 0.3 and is being decoded to three zeros instead of 30.Is there any way that I can change this or is any better encoding that I can use? If there are thirty zeros, then I would like to store the value 30 as a number(not as a string) in a matrix, so that while decoding I get the correct output.

Comment: Before encoding, i had a set of positive and negative integers and many zeros.Since decimals were not present, i encoded the set of zeros using the decimal notation i mentioned above.But this is giving wrong output during decoding.So please suggest a better encoding scheme or is there a way in matlab to decode 0.40 as 0.40 only and not as 0.4?

Comment: You can store the number of right 0s as an integer part of decimal number. Then test if the number is integer `isinteger(x)`.

Comment: Sorry `isinteger` function won't work. You'll need to compare the number and rounded number (use `fix`).

Comment: Thank you :) I I did it like this.I counted the number of zeros.Whenever this number is divisible by 10, flip that number using fliplr() and store it as a decimal.For example, if there are 40 zeros, the i flipped it and made it '04' and attached '0.' to it.So the number would be 0.04.while decoding,if the number lies between 0.0 and 0.1, the flip the number and continue decoding.